# Homomorphism density of non-dense graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408173.pdf) by Lovasz and Szegedy about limits of dense graph sequences. I am struggling to show one statement they mention.

Let $G_n$ be a sequence of simple graphs. Fix a simple graph $F$; denote the *homomorphism density* as
$$t(F,G)=\frac{|\text{Hom}(F,G)|}{|V(G)|^{|V(F)|}}.$$
Suppose that the graphs $G_n$ satisfy the property that $t(F,G_n)$ approaches a limit $t(F)$ for all $F$. I am trying to show the bolded part of following statement:

> The question is only interesting if the graphs $G_n$ are dense (i.e., they have $\Omega(|V(G_n)|^2)$ edges); **else, the limit is $0$ for every simple graph $F$ with at least one edge**.

It make sense intuitively, but I am running into some problems. First, it seems difficult to work with the negation of big-$\Omega$, so I wasn't sure how to proceed with a direct proof. The contrapositive is not too simple either, as we need the negation of a limit. I also played around with some examples; it seems like I would need a bound for $|\text{Hom}(F,G)|$ as well, which I can't really figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For functions $f,g : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$, $f = \Omega(g)$ is the same as saying $\liminf \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} > 0$. Negating this we get $\liminf \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$.

Now if $F$ has at least one edge $e$, then we can bound the number of homomorphisms from $F$ to $G$ from above by $2 \cdot |E(G)| \cdot |V(G)|^{|V(F)|-2}$, since the latter gives the number of mappings from $F$ to $G$ that send $e$ to some edge of $G$ (this can be done in $2\cdot |E(G)|$ ways) and send the rest of the vertices of $F$ to arbitrary vertices of $G$. This gives

$$0 \leq t(F,G_n) \leq 2 \cdot \frac{|E(G_n)|}{|V(G_n)|^2}$$

By assumption, the right side has a subsequence tending to $0$, and $t(F,G_n)$ is convergent, so the limit can only be $0$.

Comment: Perfect! I really struggled to come up with the correct bound.